# Unable to sign in to Tomcat Manager with correct username password and roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I am trying to sign in to Tomcat `manager` and `host-manager` webapps which I have hosted on Amazon Web Service.

**Even after entering the correct password in the popup, the pop up keeps showing and if I cancel it, then I am redirected to 401 error page**

I have updated `/etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml` correctly.

It stopped working after I added `<Context path="" docBase="mywebapp" debug="0" privileged="true" />` inside server.xml

**/etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="supermanager" password="superpassword" roles="manager-gui" />

<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="superadmin" password="superpassword" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" proxyPort="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="MYDOMAIN.COM">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="MYDOMAIN.COM"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="mywebapp" debug="0" privileged="true" /> 

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**/etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml(host-manager.xml)**

**/etc/tomcat8/Catalina/MYDOMAIN.COM/manager.xml(host-manager.xml)**

```
<Context path="/manager" 
        docBase="/usr/share/tomcat8-admin/manager"
        antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was tried to login using Google Chrome instead of Firefox and VOILA!

**It worked!!!**